# How to upload the diff of a file using file_put api in dropbox

Tags: dropbox

How can I upload the diff of a file using file_put api in dropbox? I am wondering would dropbox provide support for uploading or downloading just the diff of the file.

I am not using dropbox sync tool.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to send or receive only a diff, the smallest unit is the whole file.